# Allowing the user to comment/reply in a webpage?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am creating an ASP.NET C# web application and I am looking for the easiest way to do a comments system.

I'll explain.

I have a page containing Items (list items containing texts)

I want the users to be able to click on one, and then he is allowed to reply or comment to it. and he can see what others have replied too.

Is there a library or API that can do that? and if not can you give me tips on how to do it?

Comment: Have you looked at http://disqus.com/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at systems like [DISQUS](http://disqus.com/) or [Livefyre](http://www.livefyre.com/). The benefit of using such services (besides avoiding development) is social integration.